# Function return component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, async.js, react-component

for my application I want to put in place a form that when it's submitted makes appears some information.

Here is what I did:

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.search= this.search.bind(this);
  };

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    let input = event.target;
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = input.value;
    this.setState({[name]: value})
  };

  async search(event){
    event.preventDefault);
    const searchNumber = this.state.search;
    const getOrderInventoryList = ...
    return (<p>Order inventory list: {getOrderInventoryList }</p>)
  };

  render(){
    return(
      <div className='App'>
        <form onSubmit={this.search}>
          <input name='search' type='text' required 
                 onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
        </form>
        {this.search}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I already verified with a console.log that the search function is working, but I can't make appear its return... I already tried a few things but I don't know where I made an error :/.

So I would like to ask for some help please.

I thank in advance anyone who will take the time to help me.

Comment: Updated this in state. That is what state for. when you update your state. Your component will re-render and show this inside render

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Do you mean that I update the `search` function in state ? Or do you mean that I add a `state` in the constructor and add inside it, a `search` ?

Comment: You need to basically add another state variable in constructor. And inside search you have to update your state via `setState`. The value would be `getOrderInventoryList` and this will render your component. Inside `render` check if state has value . If it has the show it